# TensorFlow: Allocator ran out of memory trying to allocate

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I've got a DiscoGAN which I've built with Tensorflow Slim. The code executes on a CPU, but throws an out of memory error when trying to run it on a GPU. The stack trace shows the following error multiple times in a single execution:

`Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 288.00MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.`

That size for that error varies (see full stack trace below) - sometimes it doesn't even get to 288 mb. I've seen 4 bytes shown as an error.

I'm just testing execution right now. I have a batch size of 12 (over 72 images) and each image is 64x64x3.

Some other people who had similar errors managed to sort this problem out by adding the following to their code:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config = config)
```

However this didn't do anything to resolve my problem.

Stack trace is: https://pastebin.com/qeisC6PC (too big to paste in here)

Comment: Hi did you manage to solve the problem?